# Video player control with keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, css, keyboard, html5-video

I want to build a video playlist using html css javascript.
I looked through google and youtube and found relevant tutorials
But all of those controls the video using the mouse
Can anyone please direct me to a source that helps me learn video controls using the only keyboard

Thanks in advance

Comment: one way to solve your problem is to look up the video player API, and bind the keystroke events to those player API.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById("videoplayer");

    function playPause() {
        if (myVideo.paused)
            myVideo.play();
        else
            myVideo.pause();
    }

    function makeBig() {
        myVideo.width = 560;
    }

    function makeSmall() {
        myVideo.width = 320;
    }

    function makeNormal() {
        myVideo.width = 420;
    }
```

Comment: <video id="videoplayer" src="your video path" controls="controls"></video>

Comment: Tip: after html loaded, then add script.